# can I draw polygons on texture with GLSL?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsles

I'm completely new to OpenGL so my question might sound stupid but I'm trying to do one thing for more then week and I got completely stuck.

I'm trying to draw a globe that you can rotate and zoom and pick the country on Android. There are no problems with rotation but there are some with zooming (texture looks ugly if camera come closer) and I have no idea how to implement country picking. I have an arrays for each country with lat,log for each vertex of country border. But how can I draw it on the sphere ?

I've been trying to convert lat,long to zyx and draw lines but there is a triangulation issue to build polygons. Is it possible to draw texture on run-time with shaders? and is it possible to get a touch point on texture ? (I'd like to highlight selected country by filling it with another color)

I don't need a map, just a countries with one color, borders with another one and rest of the globe with third one.

I'm using [Rajawali](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali) lib for this purpose. Although it is opensource but it has no comment and tiny doc is outdated so if you know better framework please suggest me.

Comment: any idea, did you overcome this issue?

Comment: @zIronManBox I did not try to implement it but idea is to map world coordinates LLA to 0-1 rectangle and return color of ground/water/border if incoming point belong to one of these peaces. So shader should contain quite intensive logic.